# cumulative distribution function, inverse and quantile

Tags: probability, quantile, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have some issues with the cumulative distribution function ( denoted by $F$ of a random variable $X$, his quantile $Q_X(\alpha)$ and the inverse of the cumulative distribution function $F^{-1}$.

Here my thoughts :

1) The inverse $F^{-1}$ does not always exists expecially if F is not bijective ( continuous and strictly monotonic and therefore strictly increasing because $F$ is a a cumulative distribution function) .

2) the quantile $Q_X(\alpha)=inf \{x\in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } F(x)\le \alpha \} $ 
 always exits and is well define.

3) if $F$ the cumulative distribution is strictly increasing therefore $Q_X=F^{-1}$.

Are my thoughts true or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please i need it for my Master thesis.

Comment: I think these are all right, yeah. The only heads up I'd give you is that not all probability distributions have the real numbers as their domain - but if you are dealing with this situation, what you said is right.

Comment: thanks for your answer.